# Use of Gradle plugin and its internal working

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am new to Gradle and would like to know how the below code works.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'net.tech'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.1.1'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What does this plugin do? How it works?

It tried without **plugin** by adding the version in the dependencies and it works. Then why we need plugin?